# Hover style in css is disabled by javascript codes, how to use them?

Tags: javascript, css

there is some images with `grayscale(1)` by default and when you hover on images it should change to `grayscale(0)`, all of this is on css file. but i want when i click on it or when i hover on it, on both situations the image gets `grayscale(0)` but the hover effect doesn't work. i tried to put the code for `grayscale(0)` on an `addEventListener` in another function but it didn't work.

update:

i added codpen link and one line of code.

as you can see from the beginning left person is coloured because i'm showing their info. i want that when i hover on other persons, they get coloured theme while the person that their info is up is still coloured.

[link](https://codepen.io/Treebeard/pen/LYWrjjE)

```
showInfo(0);
function showInfo(person) {
    var img, info, names;

        names = document.querySelectorAll('.box h2');
        for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            names[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        names[person].style.display = 'block';
    
        info = document.querySelectorAll('.info p');
        for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            info[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        info[person].style.display = 'block';
    
        img = document.querySelectorAll('.images img');
        for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            img[i].style.filter= 'grayscale(1)'; 
        }
        img[person].style.filter= 'grayscale(0)';
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the event listeners and also any relevant CSS - particularly the hover - and the HTML structure.

Comment: You need to call showInfo after you have defined it, not just before. Are there errors in your browser's dev tools console?

Comment: @AHaworth i updated my question, also `addEventListener` was wrong solution. and there is not any errors in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your showInfo function:

```
function showInfo(person) {
    var img, info, names;

    names = document.querySelectorAll('.box h2');
    for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        names[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    names[person].style.display = 'block';

    info = document.querySelectorAll('.info p');
    for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        info[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    info[person].style.display = 'block';

    img = document.querySelectorAll('.images img');
    for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        img[i].style.filter= ''; 
    }
    img[person].style.filter= 'grayscale(0)';
}
showInfo(0);
```

The change is very small and that gets you to the required behaviour:

```
for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].style.filter= ''; 
}
```

Comment: i updated my question and added codepen link. as you can see from the beginning left person is coloured because i'm showing their info. i want that when i hover on other persons, they get coloured theme while the person that their info is up is still coloured.

Comment: @P... i have update the answer basis your codepen example. If this helps, please upvote and mark this as answered.